# conditional expectation of univariate normal given realization of multivariate normal

Tags: normal-distribution, conditional-probability, conditional-expectation

Consider the random variable $\textbf{x} = (x_1, x_2, ..., x_N)$ where $x_i \sim N(\mu_i, \sigma_i)$ for $i=1,2,...,N$ and $\textbf{x} \sim N(\mu, \sigma)$ where $N$ stands for normal distribution, $\mu = E[\textbf{x}]$ (expectation) and $\sigma$ is the covariance matrix and $\sigma_i$ is the standard deviation of $x_i$.

Now consider $\textbf{Y} = \sum_{i=1}^{N}w_i x_i = \textbf{w}' \textbf{x}$ with $\sum_{i=1}^{N}w_i = 1$. The vector $\textbf{w}$ is a vector of constants.

What can we say about $E[w_ix_i|\textbf{Y} = L]$ where $L$ is an arbitrary scalar?

I have found that

$E[w_ix_i|\textbf{Y} = L] = w_i\mu_i + \frac{cov(w_ix_i, \textbf{Y})}{Var(\textbf{Y})}(1-\mu)$. Is this correct? If yes, how do I arrive there?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In general, if the random variables $U$, $V$ are jointly normally distributed, the conditional expectation of $U$ given $V$ is
$$
\mathbb{E}(U|V) = \mathbb{E}(U) + \mathrm{Cov}(U,V) \mathrm{Var}(V)^{-1}\left[V - \mathbb{E}(V) \right]\,.
$$

In your example, any linear combination of $w_i x_i$ and $Y$ can be expressed as a linear combination of $(x_1, \ldots, x_N)$, which are jointly normally distributed. We deduce that $w_i x_i$ and $Y$ are jointly normal.

You have $\mathbb{E}(w_i x_i)=w_i\mu_i$, $\mathbb{E}(Y)=\mathbf{w}' \boldsymbol\mu$, $\mathrm{Var}(Y)=\mathbf{w}' \boldsymbol\sigma \mathbf{w}$, and $\mathrm{Cov}(w_i x_i,Y)=w_i \{\boldsymbol{\sigma}\}'_i \mathbf{w}$, where $\{\boldsymbol{\sigma}\}'_i$ denotes the $i$th row of the covariance matrix $\boldsymbol\sigma$.

Putting everything together gives
$$
\mathbb{E}(w_i x_i|Y=L) = w_i\mu_i + \frac{w_i \{\boldsymbol{\sigma}\}'_i \mathbf{w}}{\mathbf{w}' \boldsymbol\sigma \mathbf{w}}\left(L - \mathbf{w}' \boldsymbol\mu \right)\,.
$$